# Printing a receipt in Java Swing app using a POS printer (Kitchen printer)

Tags: java, javapos

In my project the clients needs to print a receipt using a POS printer which can be done using
JAVA POS.
i searched on net no useful material until now but came across
1.JavaPOS
2.JPos

Could someone please guide which i should go ahead with JAVA POS or JPos. 
The application
is based on Java Swing desktop not web based.

Really stuck at this any help would be very useful

Comment: In my own experience ever vendor implements it differently. Also, 1 and 2 are the same thing. That is, JPos is short for JavaPOS.

Comment: For an epson printer you can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839049/how-can-i-use-javapos-to-print-reciepts-with-an-epson-printer/30839050#30839050 For all other printers the things you have to do are equal: Install the driver, generate a jpos.xml which lets your program now how to talk to the printers and then write Java code using these printers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in straight java, depending on how the printer is attached. Here is some code I used:

```
 private void    printMailer(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("LPT1");  
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);  
        ps.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        ps.println("\t\t\t" + rs.getString("FIRSTNAME")+ " " + rs.getString("SURNAME"));
        ps.println("\t\t\t" + rs.getString("ADDRESSLINE1"));
        ps.println("\t\t\t" + rs.getString("ADDRESSLINE2"));
        ps.println("\t\t\t" + rs.getString("ADDRESSLINE3"));
        ps.println("\t\t\t" + rs.getString("ADDRESSLINE4"));
        ps.println("\f");
        ps.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught Exception printing mailer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear friend, I have a Vega7000 Series  EFT-POS terminal. Do you have any idea how can I develop program for it? What kind of tools and IDEs and Documents am I need? Where can I find this requirements? And does it have JVM? i.e. does it support Java applications or I must use another programming language? Any light on this issue highly appreciated.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't know anything about that specific printer.